# Android GCM crashes when app is stopped

Tags: service, crash, google-cloud-messaging

I’m trying to implement an Android app with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).
My specific Server is written by PHP and my Client is an Android app.
Push notification messages are received well when the app is running. The logcat is this:

```
07-28 07:49:56.991: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(13254): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
07-28 07:49:56.991: V/GCMRegistrar(13254): Setting the name of retry receiver class to com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMBroadcastReceiver
07-28 07:49:57.011: D/GGCMBroadcastReceiver(13254): Servicio: com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService
07-28 07:49:57.011: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(13254): GCM IntentService class: com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService
07-28 07:49:57.021: V/GCMBaseIntentService(13254): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-<<<MyProjectNumber>>>-1
07-28 07:49:57.026: D/GGCMIntentService(13254): Mensaje recibido: <<<MySendedMessage>>>
```

but when it is stopped (not paused), if I send a message from the host, appears the typical Toast crash.
The logcat error is this:

```
07-28 07:50:06.381: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(13294): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
07-28 07:50:06.386: V/GCMRegistrar(13294): Setting the name of retry receiver class to com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMBroadcastReceiver
07-28 07:50:06.386: D/GGCMBroadcastReceiver(13294): Servicio: com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService
07-28 07:50:06.386: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(13294): GCM IntentService class: com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService
07-28 07:50:06.396: D/AndroidRuntime(13294): Shutting down VM
07-28 07:50:06.396: W/dalvikvm(13294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163bc50)
07-28 07:50:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(13294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 07:50:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(13294): Process: com.planetdevices.android.loyalty, PID: 13294
07-28 07:50:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(13294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I guess the issue is about wake up the Service, but actually I test too much things and I am really confused and exhausted…

I have made a package in a library project to implement GCM. The code is this:

> GGCMIntentService.java

```
package com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm;

...

/**
 * @author AppAcoustiC <p>
 * Servicios GCM. Básicamente son todo callbacks.
 */
public class GGCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String tag = "GGCMIntentService";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public GGCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID); // Llamamos a la superclase
    } // GGCMIntentService()

    /**
     * Es lo que hace al registrarse el dispositivo.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(tag, "Dispositivo registrado: regId = " + registrationId);
        Log.d("name: ", GGCM.name);
        Log.d("email: ", GGCM.email);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered)); // Mostramos un mensaje informativo por pantalla
        GServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId, GGCM.name, GGCM.email); // Nos registramos en nuestro Servidor dedicado (Planet Devices)
    } // onRegistered()

    /**
     * Es lo que se hace al eliminar el registro.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(tag, "Eliminado el registro del dispositivo.");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered)); // Mostramos un mensaje informativo por pantalla
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) { // Si ya está registrado en nuestro Servidor
            GServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId); // Se desregistra de éste
        } else {
            // Este callback se hace al tratar de borrar el registro desde la clase ServerUtilities cuando el registro en el Servidor falla
            Log.i(tag, "Se ha ignorado el callback de anulación de registro.");
        }
    } // onUnregistered()

    /**
     * Notificación recibida.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(GCommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE); // Recojo el mensaje
        Log.d(tag, "Mensaje recibido: " + message);

        displayMessage(context, message); // Lo mostramos por pantalla
        generateNotification(context, message); // Se lo notificamos al usuario (mensaje emergente)
    } // onMessage()

    /**
     * Cuando se borran los mensajes.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(tag, "Recibida la notificación de mensajes eliminados.");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total); // Recojo el string y el nº de mensajes borrados   SERÁ SIEMPRE EL MISMO STRING AL COGERLO DE LOS R.STRING ???
        displayMessage(context, message); // Lo mostramos por pantalla
        generateNotification(context, message); // Se lo notificamos al usuario (mensaje emergente)
    } // onDeletedMessages()

    /**
     * Al producirse un error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(tag, "Error recibido: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId)); // Lo mostramos por pantalla
    } // onError()

    /**
     * Al producirse un error recuperable.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(tag, "Recibido error recuperable: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId)); // Lo mostramos por pantalla
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId); // Devolvemos un booleano para saber como ha ido la cosa
    } // onRecoverableError()

    /**
     * Genera una notificación para que el usuario sea informado de que ha recibido un mensaje.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher; // Icono que aparece en la barra de notificaciones (será el de la app desde donde creemos el objeto GGCM)
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Instante en el que se produce la notificación

        // Creamos la notificación:
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);


        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name); // Título de la notificación (Nombre de la app)

        // Gestionamos el Intent de la notificación:
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, GGCM.NotificationActivity); //  Lo configuramos para que empiece una nueva Actividad (NotificationActivity)
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sonido de notificación por defecto

        // ¡¡¡ POR SI QUEREMOS USAR NUESTRO PROPIO SONIDO PERSONALIZADO !!!
        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; // Vibra (si la vibración está activa, claro)

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification); // Notificamos (con todos los parámetros incluidos)
    } // generateNotification()

} // GGCMIntentService
```

> GGCM.java

```
package com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm;

...

/**
 * @author AppAcoustiC <p>
 * Engloba todo lo que conlleva el sistema Google Cloud Messaging.
 */
public class GGCM {

    private final String tag = "GGCM";
    private Context context;

    // Variables que meteremos en la base de datos de nuestro Servidor particular:
    static String name;
    static String email;

    static Class<?> NotificationActivity;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask; // Tarea de registro
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mUnregisterTask; // Tarea de eliminación del registro

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param context Contexto de la Actividad.
     * @param SERVER_URL Base URL del Servidor (directorio raíz).
     * @param SENDER_ID ID del proyecto en cuestión registrado para usar GCM.
     * @param userName Nombre del usuario de la aplicación.
     * @param cls Actividad que se inicia al pulsar las notificaciones recibidas.
     */
    public GGCM(final Context context,
                String SERVER_URL,
                String SENDER_ID,
                String userName,
                Class<?> cls) {
        // Primero de nada, comprobamos que está todo en orden para que el GCM funcione.
        // Qué el dispositivo soporta GCM y que el Manifest está bien configurado. Esto, una vez testeado se puede comentar:
        //checker(context);

        // Comprobacion rutinaria de que tenemos inicializadas la variables que indican el Servidor y el ID del proyecto GCM:
        G_A.checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
        G_A.checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

        // Asignamos los parámetros a las variables que usamos dentro del paquete:
        this.context = context;
        GCommonUtilities.SERVER_URL = SERVER_URL;
        GCommonUtilities.SENDER_ID = SENDER_ID;
        name = userName;
        email = G_A.getEmailAdress(context);
        NotificationActivity = cls;

        // Comprobamos la conexión a internet:
        GConnectionDetector gCD = new GConnectionDetector(context);
        if (!gCD.isConnectingToInternet()) { // Si no hay internet
            // Creamos nuestro Diálogo de alerta particular
            GAlertDialog.showAlertDialog(context,
                                         "Error de conexión a Internet",
                                         "Por favor, conéctese para poder hacer uso de la aplicación.",
                                         false);

            return; // Paramos la ejecución del programa
        }

        context.registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(GCommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION)); // Registramos el receptor
    } // GGCM()

    /**
     * Registra el dispositivo en el que está instalada la app.
     */
    public void registerDevice() {
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context); // Obtenemos el ID de registro
        if (regId.equals("")) { // Si es "" es que aún no estamos registrados
            GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCommonUtilities.SENDER_ID); // Nos registramos
            Log.i(tag, "Nos acabamos de registrar en el GCM.");
        } else {
            // El dispositivo ya está registrado. Comprobamos el Servidor:
           if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
                // Nos saltamos el registro en el Servidor. Simplemente mostramos un mensaje por pantalla:
                G_A.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.already_registered), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Log.i(tag, "Ya está registrado en nuestro Servidor.");
           } else {
                // Tratamos de registrarnos de nuevo. Hay que hacerlo mediante una Tarea Asíncrona:
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        boolean registered = GServerUtilities.register(context, regId, name, email);

                        // Si llegados a este punto, todos los intentos de registrar el dispositivo a nuestro Servidor (Planet Devices) fallan,
                        // necesitaremos desregistrar el dispositivo desde GCM. La aplicación tratará de registrarse de nuevo cuando se reinicie.
                        // Hay que tener en cuenta que GCM enviará una devolución de llamada (callback) de borrado de registro al finalizar,
                        // pero GGCMIntentService.onUnregistered() lo ignorará:
                        if (!registered) {
                            GCMRegistrar.unregister(context); // Eliminamos el registro
                        }

                        return null;
                    } // doInBackground()

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null; // Liberamos memoria
                    } // onPostExecute()
                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null); // Ejecutamos la tarea
           }
        }
    } // registerDevice()

    /**
     * Elimina el registro del dispositivo que tiene instalada la aplicación.
     */
    public void unregisterDevice() {
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context); // Obtenemos el ID de registro
        //GServerUtilities.unregister(context, regId);

        if (regId.equals("")) { // Si es "" es que aún no estamos registrados
            Log.i(tag, "Nos estamos aún registrados. No se puede anular el registro.");
            G_A.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.already_unregistered), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // ESTO NO FUNCIONA COMO BEBERÍA !!!
        } else {
                // Tratamos de eliminar el registro. Hay que hacerlo mediante una Tarea Asíncrona:
                mUnregisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        GServerUtilities.unregister(context, regId); // Nos "desregistramos"

                        return null;
                    } // doInBackground()

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mUnregisterTask = null; // Liberamos memoria
                    } // onPostExecute()
                };
                mUnregisterTask.execute(null, null, null); // Ejecutamos la tarea
        }
    } // unregisterDevice()

    /**
     * Comprobamos si el dispositivo soporta GCM y que el Manifest está bien configurado.
     */
    private void checker(Context context) {
        try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
            Log.i(tag, "El dispositivo soporta GCM.");

            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
            Log.i(tag, "El Manifest está correctamente.");
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "El dispositivo no soporta GCM.", e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "El Manifest no está bien configurado.", e);
        }
    } // checker()

    /**
     * Manejador para recibir mensajes.
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(GCommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE); // Recogemos el mensaje

            GWakeLocker.acquire(context); // Mantenemos el dispositivo a la espera de que acabe de procesar todo el mensaje (para que no entre en modo de suspensión)

            // SI TENEMOS ESTO PUESTO MUESTRA TOAST CADA VEZ QUE ENVIAMOS UNA NOTIFICACIÓN PUSH !!!!!:
            //G_A.showToast(context, newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Lo mostramos por pantalla 

            GWakeLocker.release(); // Liberamos para ahorrar energía (importante para optimizar los recursos de la batería)
        } // onReceive()
    };

    /**
     * Realiza las acciones pertinentes cuando se hace un callback de onDestroy desde la Actividad que llama al objeto GGCM.
     */
    public void setOnDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true); // Cancelamos la Tarea de registro
        }

        context.unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver); // Desregistramos el manejador de mensajes ?????????????????? ESTO CREO QUE HAY QUE QUITARLO, SINO NO LLEGARÁN LOS MENSAJES EMERGENTES
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(context); // Destruimos
    } // setOnDestroy()

} // GGCM
```

> GCommonUtilities.java

```
package com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author AppAcoustiC <p>
 * Utilidades comunes a todo el paquete. Las cargamos en el contructor de GGCM al hacer la llamada.
 */
public final class GCommonUtilities {

    static String SERVER_URL; // Base URL del Servidor
    static String SENDER_ID; // ID del proyecto en cuestión registrado para usar GCM

    // Intentos usados para mostrar un mensaje en la pantalla:
    static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.DISPLAY_MESSAGE"; // Nombre del paquete
    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message"; // Extra

    /**
     * Notifica a la interfaz de usuario (UI) que tiene que mostrar un mensaje.<p>
     * Este método está definido en el Helper común porque es usado por ambos: la interfaz de usuario y el Servicio.
     * @param context Contexto de la actividad.
     * @param message Mensaje a mostrar.
     */
    static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION); // Instanciamos el intento
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message); // Añadimos el mensaje que hemos metido como parámetro
        context.sendBroadcast(intent); // Hace el envío asíncrono
    } // displayMessage()

} // GCommonUtilities
```

> GGCMBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * @author AppAcoustiC <p>
 * Implementa el receptor de GCM.<p>
 * De este modo irá al paquete donde tenemos nosotros nuestro GCMIntentService. 
 */
public class GGCMBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    private final String tag = "GGCMBroadcastReceiver";

    /**
     * Devuelve el nombre de la clase donde tenemos implementado el servicio. 
     */
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        String s = GGCMIntentService.class.getName();
        Log.d(tag, "Servicio: " + s);

        return s;
    } // getGCMIntentServiceClassName()

} // GGCMBroadcastReceiver
```

> GServerUtilities.java

```
package com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm;

...

import com.appacoustic.android.g.R;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

/**
 * @author AppAcoustiC <p>
 * Utilidades de comunicación con nuestro Servidor (Planet Devices).
 */
public final class GServerUtilities {

    private static final String TAG = "GServerUtilities";

    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5; // Nº máximo de intentos
    private static final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000; // Tiempo para echarse atrás
    private static final Random random = new Random(); // Objeto auxiliar para generar números aleatorios 

    /**
     * Registra el dispositivo en nuestro Servidor.
     * @param context Contexto de la Actividad.
     * @param regId ID de registro.
     * @param name Nombre del usuario.
     * @param email Email del usuario.
     * @return Si el registro ha sido correcto.
     */
    static boolean register(final Context context, final String regId, String name, String email) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registrando dispositivo... (regId = " + regId + ")");
        String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/register.php"; // Dirección donde tenemos el *.php que implementa el registro

        // Parámetros:
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId); // ID de registro
        params.put("name", name); // Nombre
        params.put("email", email); // Email

        long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000); // Tiempo para echarse atrás (y un poco más cada vez)

        // Una vez GCM devuelve el ID de registro, necesitamos registrar dicho ID en nuestro Servidor particular:
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) { // Si el Servidor ha caído, lo volveremos a intentar alguna vez más
            Log.d(TAG, "Intento de registro nº " + i + ".");
            try {
                displayMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS)); // Mostramos por pantalla
                post(serverUrl, params); // Hacemos el post con los parámetros hacia nuestro Servidor
                GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true); // Indicamos que se registra

                // Mostramos por pantalla que todo ha ido bien:
                String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
                GCommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Aquí estamos simplificando el manejo de errores. En una aplicación real
                // se debería de volver a procesar sólo los errores recuperables (como HTTP error code 503, e.g.):
                Log.e(TAG, "Fallo tratando de registrarse. Nº de intento: " + i, e);
                if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    break; // Si ya hemos gastado todos los intentos, paramos la aplicación
                }
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Parando por " + backoff + " ms antes de volver a intentar.");
                    Thread.sleep(backoff); // Retardo
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Hilo interrumpido: Abortamos los restantes intentos.");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Actividad terminada antes de que la hayamos completado

                    return false;
                }

                backoff *= 2; // Incrementamos exponencialemente el tiempo de espera
            }
        }

        // Si hemos llegado hasta aquí es porque hemos condumido todos los intentos.
        // Mostramos que ha habido un error:
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error, MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        GCommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);

        return false;
    } // register()

    /**
     * Anula el registro del par "cuenta-dispositivo" en nuestro Servidor.
     * @param context Contexto de la Actividad.
     * @param regId ID de registro.
     */
    static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Anulando el registro del dispositivo... (regId = " + regId + ")");
        String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/unregister.php"; // Archivo *.php encargado de implementar el proceso 

        // Parámetros:
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId); // Sólo hace falta el ID de registro para eliminarlo 

        try {
            post(serverUrl, params); // Hacemos el post con los parámetros hacia nuestro Servidor
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false); // Indicamos que se desregistra

            // Mostramos por pantalla que todo ha ido bien:
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
            GCommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // En este punto, el dispositivo está desregistrado de GCM, pero permanece registrado en nuestro Servidor de Planet Devices.
            // Podríamos tratar de anular el registro de nuevo, pero no es necesario, ya que si el Servidor trata de enviar un mensaje al dispositivo,
            // se generará un mensaje de error tipo "No registrado" y se debería de anular el registro del dispositivo.

            // Mostramos que ha habido un error anulando el registro:
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error, e.getMessage());
            GCommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        }
    } // unregister()

    /**
     * Realiza un POST a nuestro Servidor.
     * @param endpoint Dirección del POST.
     * @param params Parámetros de la solicitud.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
        URL url; // Dirección del POST
        try {
            url = new URL(endpoint); // La inicializamos
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL incorrecta: " + endpoint); // La dirección no es correcta
        }

        // Creamos un StringBuilder para cargar el contenido del POST:
        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();

        // Construimos el cuerpo del POST usando los parámetros:
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
            bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=').append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                bodyBuilder.append('&');
            }
        }

        String body = bodyBuilder.toString(); // Pasamos a un único String todo el StringBuilder
        Log.v(TAG, "Enviando '" + body + "' a " + url);

        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(); // Convertimos a bytes para que puedan viajar por la red mdiante un Stream
        HttpURLConnection conn = null; // Conexión
        try {
            // Abrimos la conexión y la configuramos:
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");


            // Posteamos la solicitud:
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream(); // Instanciamos el flujo
            out.write(bytes); // Enviamos los datos
            out.close(); // Cerramos el Stream


            // Manejamos la respuesta:
            int status = conn.getResponseCode(); // Obtenemos el código de respuesta desde el Servidor (el 200 indica que todo ha ido bien)
            if (status != 200) { // Si no es el código 200, es porque ha habido un error
                throw new IOException("Envío fallido con error de código: " + status);
            }
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect(); // Al final desconectamos
            }
        }
    } // post()

} // GServerUtilities
```

I have written an Android app which calls the library like that:

> Call in onCreate()

```
// Creamos nuestro objeto GCM:
gGCM = new GGCM(context,
                Att.SERVER_URL,
                Att.SENDER_ID,
                Att.userName,
                NotificationActivity.class);

//gGCM.registerDevice(); // Nos registramos directamente

//gGCM.unregisterDevice();
```

I have a NotificationActivity which is the Activity which is thrown when you click the push notification and so on...

Finally my Manifest is here:

> AndroidMainfest.xml

```
...

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- GCM requiere de una cuenta Google -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Se activa cuando se recibe un mensaje -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Crea un permiso específico para este paquete. Sólo esta app puede recibir estos mensajes -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.planetdevices.android.loyalty.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.planetdevices.android.loyalty.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Esta aplicación tiene permiso para registrarse y recibir mensajes de datos de Google -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Pemisos del estado de la red para detectar el status de Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Vibración -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="NotificationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
...

        <!-- Receptor -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Servicio -->
        <service android:name="com.appacoustic.android.g.gcm.GGCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well, I've solved by myself in a little drastic way, but solved anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve changed calling to SuperClass Constructor in GGCMIntentService. I have put directly the SENDER_ID as a String with its value. I have done it because when I stop the app, when that Constructor is called, throws a nullPointerException, because String “SENDER_ID” is not initialized.

```
public GGCMIntentService() {
    //super(SENDER_ID); // Llamamos a la superclase
    super("<<<ProjectNumber>>>"); // NEW WAY
} // GGCMIntentService()
```

After that, for a similar reason, I’ve put also directly Activity to start in the same Class in method generateNotification() like this:

```
Class<?> cls = null;
try {
    cls = Class.forName("<<<packageName>>>.NotificationActivity");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have put this instance a little lines below:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
```

It’s not the best solution, but it works perfectly whenever. :-)